# Youtube to MP3 Conversion in Javascript => INSERT into MYSQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, web-scraping, file-conversion

I was able to get the youtube videos scrapped off of youtube, but I am unable to convert those links into MP3 files. I would really appreciate some help since I have been stuck on this problem for quiet some time. Thank you. Here is my code,

```
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    mysql = require('mysql');

var video_list = new Array();
var video = new Object();
var req_comp = false;

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "anchor"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        request('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=motivational+video', function(err, resp, body) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var counter = 0;
            $('a').each(function() {
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                var url = "youtube.com" + $(this).attr('href');
                if (title && url.substring(11, 17) == "/watch") {
                    video = {
                        video_id : counter,
                        video_url : url,
                        video_title : title
                    };
                    video_list[counter] = video;
                    counter += 1;
                }
            });

            req_comp = true;
            console.log(req_comp + " " + video_list.length);
            var counter = 0;
            while (video_list[counter]) {
                var sql = "INSERT INTO content (video, title) VALUES ('" + video_list[counter].video_url + "', '" + video_list[counter].video_title + "');";
                con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                });
                counter++;
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question

Comment: why not using the official Youtube API ?

Comment: I tried installing a thing called npm ytdb